# Fitting a sum of sinusoids to known data

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, signal-processing, trigonometric-series

I have been trying for several months to solve what looks (on the surface) like a simple problem.  I have **9 data points** (t,y) and it is known that these points represent the *turning points of a continuous waveform* which is the sum of three sinusoids:

$y(t) = a.cos(u.t) + b.sin(u.t) + c.cos(v.t) + d.sin(v.t) + e.cos(w.t) + f.sin(w.t)$

So we know that $y(t)$ passes through the nine points and we also know that the derivative $dy(t)/dt$ is zero at the nine points (see example graph at the end of this post).

So we have 18 equations in nine unknowns (a,b,c,d,e,f,u,v,w), nine from $y(t)$ and nine from $dy(t)$.

I have tried a number of approaches, especially linear algebra (e.g least squares, SVD, etc) but am stuck at every turn!  It is easy to find an expression for (a,b,c,d,e,f) in terms of (u,v,w), thus reducing the size of the problem from 9 variables to 3, but after that the problem is fighting me!

Can anyone help?

Many thanks!

In this image, the nine blue circles are the known data points.  The smooth red curve is what I am seeking:-

[image: Sample problem made from known data]

Comment: You have 9 equations just be requiring that $y$ passes at the nine data points... How to you enforce the conditions on the derivative?

Comment: Hi Pierre.  Sorry, maybe I was unclear.  I believe I am right in saying that there are 9 equations for y(t) = KNOWN and also 9 equations for dy(t)/dt = ZERO.  Anne.

Comment: Can you specify the data points more precisely (the exact numerical values of $t_n$ and $y(t_n)$ for $n=1..9$? How do you know the problem is solvable?

Comment: Hi Steven.  Here are my sample _[t,y(t)]_ values that I used in the example graph in the original post:  _t = [56, 99, 163, 215, 259, 310, 362, 427, 465]_ and _y = [10.223, 1.478, 28.482, 13.793, 22.119, 10.876, 27.198. 0.742, 6.506]_.  And... I have no idea if the problem is solvable - that is why I am asking the gurus here.  It seems reasonable to me that it should have a solution given that there are sufficient equations and constraints to completely specify the problem.  But I don't know for sure....

Comment: Just an observation... a friend has a copy of the amazing, magical Eureqa package by Nutonian (as was).  We entered the _[t,y(t)]_ values and Eureqa took less than 9 seconds to find a solution.  Hence, the problem **is** clearly solvable, if only by the dark arts of artificial intelligence!